# Where do I put business logic in IOS app with Core Data?

Tags: ios, xcode

I just started exploring ios and xcode, and have starting building an app that uses Core Data.

In my model, I have 2 related entities:

- an Exam entity with an examDate and a studyStartDate
- a CalendarItem to plan/ log preparation for an exam.

[image: Section of my data model]

A part of business logic is: for all dates between studyStartDate and examDate, I want to have a CalendarItem.

So for this, I need code that creates/ deletes CalendarItems every time the the start and end of the date range (in studyStartDate and examDate) change.

In other posts (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415904/business-logic-in-mvc?lq=1)) I read that this type of business logic should go in model (not in controller). So now I need a place inside my model where I can code this.

My question is: where do I create this code? 
In the subclass of  NSManagedObject for the examItem? How do I get access to the ManagedObjectContext in examItem (which I think I need if a insert/ delete other records in my model)?
Or do I need to subclass NSManagedObjectContext and build my logic there?

I am really lost here.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to the answers below, I followed up on the database manager model - more or less. It feels like the right direction to try keep the ManagedObjects simple, and focused on single entities.

I created a class CalendarManager, which I instantiate once, in appdelegate. It receives ManagedObjectContext. It subscribes to insert/delete notifications in notification-center, and for each new Exam, it sets up Key Value Observers.

As an aside: The KVO are needed to focus on only the date items in the exam. Could not use the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification unfortunately. That would run into endless loops: adding/removing a related CalendarItem would also change Exam, which would trigger another loop.

**CalendarManager.h**

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface CalendarManager : NSObject

-(id)initWith:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;

@end
```

**CalendarManager.m**

```
#import "CalendarManager.h"
#import "Exam.h" // NSManagedObject subclass
#import "CalendarItem.h" // NSManagedObject subclass

@interface CalendarManager ()

-(void)updateCalendarItemsFor:(Exam*)exam;
-(void)setObserverFor:(Exam*)exam;
-(void)removeObserverFor:(Exam*)exam;

@property NSArray *keyPaths;
@property NSManagedObjectContext *moc;

@end
```

Works for me this way.

Comment: I do that in the subclass of NSManagedObject, I mean inside the database model itself.

Comment: So one NSManagedObject can create other NSManagedObjects? How do you access the managed-object-context from the NSManagedObject? To fetch/create/delete sibling objects, you need the MOC, right?

Comment: `id myCtx = myObj.managedObjectContext`

Comment: @wintvelt not exactly, every NSManagedObject class has their own update/delete/fetch methods, and one NSManagedObject can request another NSManagedObject to perform those op.

Comment: For eg, the Department object can fetch all the departments, but only the Employee object can fetch all the employees in a particular department. I am not sure if this is a right approach though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always create a DatabaseManager that HAS the NSManagedObjectContext and inserts/deletes. my moms are just stupid classes without any logic :P

But I wanna say that this is a matter of opinion

Comment: Could you explain how that works? What kind of class is your DatabaseManager? Where is your DBM instantiated?

Comment: I usually have a singleton class derived from NSObject that wraps everything core data related. It creates the cd stack and i instantiate it lazily using a sharedInstance method