# Android development patterns

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, model-view-controller

is there any general development patterns for android/java such as `model-view-controller (MVC)` ?
i saw this question :
[MVC pattern on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)

Comment: Check out this link http://mindtherobot.com/blog/675/android-architecture-message-based-mvc/

Answer (score 2):

There are various pattern used in android frameworks like

Broadcast receiver uses (observer pattern) remoter service invocation uses Proxy pattern) view and view group uses (Composite pattern) Media framework uses (Fascade pattern)

A disucssion is already there here [Which design patterns are used on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916209/which-design-patterns-are-used-on-android)

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/

Have a look at those links. It may help you.