# Android: nesting FrameLayouts - what is the exact performance overhead?

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-framelayout

In order to implement a clean architecture with separate and reusable UI components, I need to have hierarchies of nested `FrameLayouts` (up to 3-4 nested `FrameLayouts`), all of which have both `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `match_parent` (the general idea behind that architecture is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30628530/2463035)).

I came to wonder if there is any noticeable performance overhead associated with this practice of nesting `FrameLayouts`. In order to make the question less abstract, let's discuss it in context of two concrete hierarchies: "static" hierarchy (nothing moves on the screen), and "scrollable" hierarchy (user can scroll the screen).

**"Static" hierarchy:**

[image]

once the screen containing this hierarchy is shown, nothing changes anymore.

**"Scrollable" hierarchy:**

[image]

after this hierarchy is shown on the screen, the user can scroll the inner `ListView`, thus requiring redraw of the innermost `RelativeLayouts`.

I'm not worried at all about "static" hierarchy - the overhead of nested `FrameLayouts` in this case is paid once and will not impact layout's performance in any noticeable way.

- Q1: Is this assumption correct, or there are some performance-degrading scenarios which I can bump into?

What about "scrollable" layout? I wonder whether the fact that the inner `ListView` is wrapped in several `FrameLayouts` affects its scrolling performance...

- Q2: Are outer `FrameLayouts` affect nested `ListView` scrolling performance?
- Q3: If answer to Q2 is "yes", what is the exact overhead in "scrollable" case?

Comment: That answer you linked says literally nothing about nesting views

Comment: Have you found any answers to that?

Comment: @Dhaval , empiric answer only: used this approach in ~10 different apps and tested on low end devices, but never had issues due to additional FrameLayouts.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that. Actually I am your student and I am following your guidance regarding using MVC views. That’s why I was curious about how it would affect on performance.