# design patterns used by Android components

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

Last time when I was giving an interview the interviewer asked me the question that **What are the design patters used by Android components?** so I answered it by mentioning design pattern names like MVP, MVC, MVVM, etc so He interrupted me and told that this is the wrong answer and asked me to find out the answer so I googled it but it will show same as I told in the interview room, So anybody know  the correct answer, If yes then please help me with this, Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916209/which-design-patterns-are-used-on-android ; it is quite probable that being narrow-minded, he had a very concise standard list of aceptable answers. If you mentionned any that is absent from his list, you are out.

Comment: No, Actually he gave some example like Broadcast Receiver uses Notification Design pattern, View Holder uses Singleton Design Pattern. @nicolallias

Comment: @art's answer is what you are looking for in this case: your interviewer considers that architectural patterns are not design patterns. Quibbling.

Comment: Maybe he will only accept some of the oo design patterns [like these](http://www.oodesign.com/). I am not saying he is right, just trying to help to understand his thoughts...

Comment: This question is unanswerable.  There's dozens of patterns used by different parts of android.  You either missed something in the question, or he didn't understand the question and couldn't ask it right.  Leaning towards the second here.

Comment: No he asked the same question which I asked, I think you miss the word component?

Comment: Actually, the components are stuff like Activity, Service and Broadcast receiver.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MVP, MVC, MVVM are architectural patterns, not design patterns. I quote an old SO post about the question that you were asked.

[Which design patterns are used on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44618501/5500459)

Comment: There's no difference, the two terms are synonyms for each other and have been since the 80s.

Comment: Thanks man the above link you provided having enough content that I wanted. @art

Comment: @GabeSechan I could argue that the scale of the architectural patterns is more high level.  But yeah they're both patterns. I do believe though that the interviewer's question was well-phrased, but his answer kinda absolute.

Comment: @art I don't think it was-  the answer to "what patterns are used in Android" is all of them, more or less.  Asking "give me an example of a pattern used in Android" would be fine, but in that case his answer needs to be more expansive.  Honestly it sounds like an interview with a non technical person who was looking to match the answer to something his engineers wrote down as the answer.

Comment: @GabeSechan  He did ask about design patterns though, or at least that's what the 
questions says. I agree, that he could elaborate or guide the interviewee ,but the first thing that came to my mind was the most common design patterns(Observer, Builder etc). I'm not an expert at the subject, just my personal opinion.