# How are Android-Binding and Roboguice?

Tags: android, oop, design-patterns, roboguice

As a beginner for Android development, code samples I am learning from look somewhat disorganized and are hard to test or even to understand. So I followed this post suggested: [Using Dependency Injection with Roboguice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245722/android-design-patterns) and am trying to use Android-binding and Roboguice. But I am now worrying about how good they really are.

1. Are they good enough for all Android projects including ones with a couple of views?
2. After building an app with these tools, how is the app's performance in comparison without the tools? Any problem with using these tools?
3. Is there any other tool that can help me for Agile/TDD?

Comment: I am facing the same issues. Since about 2 years have passed maybe you have now a better understanding of the problem. How did you decide to build the app and what is your opinion about the frameworks? (I am actually having a look at RoboBinding instead of android-binding but I think they're quite similar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only used Roboguice and this is my opinion of it.

Roboguice is derived from Guice. So it's not really a dependency injection framework built from the grounds up for mobile environment. That being said, it can cause quite some overhead to your app.

On the other hand, I haven't seen any mobile app that reached a complexity that really needs dependency injection. I had an app the used Roboguice, but soon I realized that it's making my app more complex than it needs to be. So I stripped it out. I guess this depends a lot on the scale of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that case, how do you manage your code? When I looked at samples, each activity has a lot of inner classes and code in it. How do you test then?