# Design Pattern in Android?

Tags: android, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245722/android-design-patterns)

I would like to understand android programming on basis of Design Pattern.Which design patterns have been used in designing the
Android API?
Where can I find a study or a white paper about development principles
of the Android ?
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: This is a repeat of an existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245722/android-design-patterns

Comment: Do any of the suggestions in the existing question not work for you?