# MVC pattern in android?

Tags: android, model-view-controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC pattern in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)

I'm new to Android, I need to know that, how to create MVC pattern in an Android application?
If any one knows please guide me to right direction.....

Comment: Before opening a new question use the SEARCH: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Check below link for MVC:
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/675/android-architecture-message-based-mvc/
http://code.google.com/p/android-mvc/source/checkout