# Benifits of implementing MVC in Android

Tags: android

I want to implement **MVC** in my Android application for reasons I have heard but not realized. Can anyone lead me to implement **MVC** in my application? Kindly mention the benefits for using the same.

Thanks

Comment: This link exactly matches what you're looking for: http://www.digigene.com/architecture/android-architecture-part-2-mvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already implemented as per this post here: [MVC pattern on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)

Comment: No it's not. If you want MVC (or any variant of it such as MVP) you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The key benefit of MVC (and its variations) in general and not only for Android is separation of concerns. This means you keep business logic isolated in the Model instead of mingled with the presentation logic. In turn the Model becomes easier to unit test, modify, and reuse (when reuse is a concern at least).

I'm not sure if there is much sense in testing the View or Controller parts of MVC. The View for one thing is supposed to be as much 'dumb' as possible, to the point of lacking even presentation logic.

MVC apparently [has trouble telling where the presentation logic belongs to](https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2008/02/26/model-view-presenter-variations-on-the-basic-pattern-introduction-to-cabscsf-part-24/) -- this seems to be the reason why MVP has been created, so all this logic goes to the Presenter. So by using MVP instead of MVC you would also have the benefit of easily testable presentation logic.

MVC also allows (in theory at least) to change the user interface adopted by the application, though I'm not sure how this applies to Android (maybe for games?).

Needless to say, Android apps DO NOT implement MVC by design. Otherwise those benefits would be available to Android apps by design, which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, it allows you to plug in a different algorithms or data store/source into your app with a single line of code. So in my sample Android app, I can switch from DES, to AES to TDES encryption in one line of code. It allows you to port your algorithm to another app with a completely different user interface and architecture. So in .NET I can write a Windows Form app and then port it to  a Web Form app without re writing the core algorithm code. If you are looking for an example in Android I have a complete example [here.](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial) If you can read C# code I have an example [here.](http://www.geocities.com/jeff_louie/OOP/oop3.htm)

Have fun.
JAL

Answer (score 0):

Java has very powerful features behind it. The word MVC means at the bottom line, basically, componentization. Components are a very important definition in a OOP language like Java, and even more important to languages that implement memory allocation and handling like Java with the GC (*Garbage Collector*).

There's lots of GC algorithms & types implemented out there, each JVM has it's own number of sets, Oracle has it's own, IBM, Apache's OpenJDK, and so on and on. But the concept is almost every time the same: **reference counting**. Let's picture an example where you have an object A, that define a property of type B, and this class B has also a property to another class called C, and they are all in the same processing scope (e.g. a method). Analysing this example, the runtime (JVM) could only release "B" after "C" is out of scope (out scoped), and also "A" could not be liberated because of "B" being used by the same scope. Putting this in perspective, the scope modifiers, methods, classes, static methods and classes, final declarations, everything needs to be carefuly chosen.

Summing all together, that means not only you get a more well organised code using patterns like MVC, but also more performance in the JVM runtime, because depending on the size of your program, your GC pool can really be a bottom-neck, and fine grained java code, *with methods with a just few lines divided by a few number of classes*, will always perform better. Huge classes, with just a few methods with a lot of lines of code within, tend to perform poorly.

... and that's the beauty of things. MVC not only gives a more well organised code, but also, more performance. Hope it helps!