# MVC architecture in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC pattern in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)

I want to follow **MVC architecture** in **Android**.

How I can achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: your question is right na i had up vote...why people has down vote cannot understand

Comment: Check out my blog posts on this starting here [Android Architecture: MV?](http://doridori.github.io/Android-Architecture-MV%3F/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MVC is already implemented in Android

- You define your user interface in various XML files by resolution/hardware etc.
- You define your resources in various XML files by locale etc.
- You extend classes like `ListActivity`, `TabActivity` and make use of the XML file by inflaters
- You can create as many classes as you wish for your model
- A lot of Utils have been already written for you. `DatabaseUtils`, `Html`, etc.

Copied from: [MVC pattern on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)

See the [Example Here](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/675/android-architecture-message-based-mvc/)