# MVC like logic separation of Android apps

Tags: android

I recently began to make my first Android app, and, while learning the tricks, I messed up my code by not separating the logic. Then I wondered if there exists some sort of standard for logic separation on Android (like MVC). I would really appreciate if you could show me some ways of packaging my app in a MVC manner, or some other pattern, if any.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC pattern in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)