# Android MVC Model

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC pattern in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)

I would like to know if Android follows a MVC architecture. I am currently flowing an MVC model to build an application. The application simply will allow to send sms as emails to a server and then based on the sms send server will reponse accordingly.
please suggest me how should i approach.

My current approach is activities are separated and model are separated too. But i am having problem accessing the data's in the activity from the model classes. As normally in developing web content  i follow this approach. Without much reading android i started with this approach.
So please suggest me if my approach is wrong.

Comment: Read this [topic][1], it's very helpfull for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android/2925368#2925368

Comment: I read the posted link and thank you so much. As i already started my design on the application basically it will have Four Tabs, and all the layouts will be backed by XML File. I wish to know how BroadcastReciever actually works for multiple action?