# MVC structure in ANDROID web service projects

Tags: android, web-services

I am very new to build a web service in android. So please tell me proper structure of android  web service project. 
Should i use MVC structure for it???
or it is very complex structure for phone applications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by building web service in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web service resides on the web server and is available for use over the Internet. Android is an operating system designed for mobile devices which are clients. MVC(Model View Control) framework is already implemented in Android. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android).

You can't build a web service[in your case a web service project] that resides on a client. What you can do instead is to create the web service and let the client Android device consume it or invoke it.

Again, there are many methods and tutorials available over the web to create web services. You can create REST/WCF,SOAP etc web services.

Also, various developer tools are present that will help you achieve your task.

Remember, when working with web services you need to be careful in dealing with the response as it may occur in various formats like XML, JSON etc.
If your going ahead and working on Android later perhaps you will need to brush up your skills a bit in these technologies especially if you are new to them.

Last but not the least, as a personal opinion I would say that one should believe in himself.
No task is impossible. You just need to work hard towards achieving it.

All the best in your project.

Comment: And what to do with java classes : should i make different packages for dao , pojo and services or not?

Comment: yes that way also you can do. It depends entirely on your requirements and the flow of your project.