# MVC pattern in an Android application for drawing

Tags: java, android

I'm developing the Android application for drawing. So, I NEED to use MVC pattern for it. I have View class which the application use for drawing:

```
public class PainterView extends View implements DrawingListener {

    private Painter painter;

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Paint bitmapPaint;
    private Path path;
    private Paint paint;

    public PainterView(Context context, Painter painter) {

        super(context);
        this.painter=painter;
        this.painter.addDrawingListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (bitmap!=null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                painter.touchStart(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                painter.touchMove(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                painter.touchUp();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Bitmap bitmap, Paint bitmapPaint, Path path, Paint paint) {

        this.bitmap=bitmap;
        this.bitmapPaint=bitmapPaint;
        this.path=path;
        this.paint=paint;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Main activity:

```
public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private PainterView mMainView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Painter painter=new Painter(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
        mMainView = new PainterView(this, painter);
        setContentView(mMainView);
    }
}
```

And Painter class which keeps all algorithms (Model). Please, note, all algorithms work good:

```
public class Painter {

    private List<DrawingListener> mDrawingListeners;

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

    public Paint mPaint;
    public Bitmap mBitmap;
    public Canvas mCanvas;
    public Path mPath;
    public Paint mBitmapPaint;

    private float mX, mY;

    public Painter(int width, int height) {
        initializeGraphic(width, height);
    }

    private void initializeGraphic(int width, int height) {

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        mCanvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), new Paint(Color.BLACK));
    }

    private void drawingChanged() {
        notifyDrawingListeners();
    }

    public void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        Log.e("event", "start");
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        drawingChanged();
    }

    public void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        Log.e("event", "move");
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        drawingChanged();
    }

    public void touchUp() {
        Log.e("event", "up");
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
        drawingChanged();
    }

    public void addDrawingListener(DrawingListener listener) {
        if (mDrawingListeners==null) {
            mDrawingListeners=new ArrayList<DrawingListener>();
        }
        mDrawingListeners.add(listener);
    }   

    public void removeDrawingListener(DrawingListener listener) {
        mDrawingListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void notifyDrawingListeners() {

        for (DrawingListener listener:mDrawingListeners) {
            listener.update(mBitmap, mBitmapPaint, mPath, mPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

But I have some problems: when I touch by screen and draw then it works, but if I up my finger from screen then the screen will be black again! I.e. the application doesn't save the result of drawing. So, if I add this lines into onDraw method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (bitmap!=null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        painter.mBitmap=bitmap;
        painter.mBitmapPaint=bitmapPaint;
        painter.mPaint=paint;
        painter.mPath=path;
    } 
}
```

then it works! But I don't understand why! The application uses the same links, why I need to change it again after drawing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android implicity follows `MVC` pattern, so you just need not bother.

[MVC pattern on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)

Comment: This answer is certainly not constructive to the questioner's needs. To tell him/her not to do something they obviously need to do is counter-productive. Further, the question that you link to, though the accepted answer makes this assertion, keeps this under hot debate. In fact, the contrary comments within the answer are rated above the actual answer. I would consider reposting your answer to address the OPs actual need.