# Developing Model and using it for both Mobile and Tablets

Tags: android, model-view-controller, business-logic

I have a team that developed an iOS App for both iPhone and iPad.

They used MVC (in built with iOS may be?). They built the business logic and used it both on iPhone and iPad with just different UIs / Views and same controller (possibly?).

How do we achieve this in Android? MVC / MVP?
How do we structure the files in this case?

Comment: Not sure why a down vote? Is it a bad question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got that described in Android SDK documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html). From my experience - if you want to do this right, you have to design it right and split your application into `fragments`, otherwise you would end unsuccessfully trying to make layout files for your tablet version that would make app look less crappy it would be looking w/o proper design.

Answer (score 0):

Android and iOS are significantly different implementations, data, ui, and control can be conceptually separated out but not in exactly the same way as in iOS

Here is a similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android) along with some answers