# Which Design Pattern is good for Android application development

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

**Design patterns** represent the best practices used by experienced object-oriented software developers. Design patterns are solutions to general problems that software developers faced during software development.

There are three basic kinds of design patterns:

1.Structural

2.Creational

3.Behavioral

Different design patterns are there like 1. MVC 2. Singlton 3. Factory method 4. Lazy initialization etc.

I worked on to find out which design pattern is good for Android. Some posts says the android is MVC based and other said no.

So can any one please guide me which design pattern Android support or suitable for android application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC pattern in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)

Comment: @BornToWin He is asking about design pattern for java code in android not for UX.

Comment: @RoyIacob my question is in broad sense not specific to MVC only. Which design pattern is good and why ?

Comment: Look at the java design patterns, they all exist in android too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns

Comment: Any design pattern can be used . But you will have to choose the one which meets your requirements. Usually a design pattern is at problem / application (or lower) level, not at framework level. Frameworks themselves have design patterns (sometimes..) But you should focus on what design pattern solves your problem rather than looking at a particular design pattern to suit you requirement each time you code. example : Your data model will be singleton, you could use a producer / consumer (observer) to read data from one place and update it in another (or you might want to use polling).